# How do I make a progress bar get the value of a text-type input?

Tags: javascript, php, progress-bar, textinput

I am developing an application in which the user must write in a text type input (or numeric type) the percentage in which they dominate a skill and I want the progress bar to automatically have that value. I need help with that, preferably with PHP only (if possible), but no problem if you include JAVA, I just want it to work.

I used this java script code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = $("#value");
}
</script>
```

and my HTML code is :

```
<input type="number" id="value" max="100" step="10">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<progress id="myProgress" value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: We can not write the code for you but we can correct your code if ANY.

Comment: well, you can use jQuery and on input `blur` check if user input is a correct percentage, and if so simply set your input type to `hidden` and create progressbar. Only with php it's impossible.

Comment: Hi @guest271314, I used this java script code: <script>
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("myProgress").value = $("#value");
      }
      </script>  and my HTML code is this  <input type="number" id="value" max="100" step="10">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
            <progress id="myProgress" value="22" max="100"> </progress>     but it does not work

Comment: @SergioMendez What issue are you having? _"but it does not work"_ Can you describe "does not work" at text of Question, create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Update your question with your code in readable format pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this below. You don't need to use jQuery in order to achieve it.

```js
function func() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myProgress");    
    
    x.value = document.getElementById("value").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="value" max="100" step="10">
<button onclick="func()">Try it</button>
<progress id="myProgress" value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you want to have the progress bar update as the user is typing in your text-input. You want to add an event listener for the 'keyup' action so whenever the user releases one of the keys it will execute the code you put in the event listener's body.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", () => {

// code to update the progressbar styles here

}, false);
```